# ReactJS | How to convert a local directory (with empty subdirectories) to a directory-tree JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, file, directory, directory-tree

I have a local directory with this structure (no files, only subfolders):

```
+ root-dir
   + sub-dir-1
      + sub-dir-1-1

   + sub-dir-2
      + sub-dir-2-1
      + sub-dir-2-1
```

I want to select this folder ('root-dir') from local and then generate a directory-tree JSON.

### Solutions I've tried:

### Input file

```
<input type="file" directory allowdirs webkitdirectory/>
```

The input file works only if there are actual files within a folder.

### FileSystemDirectoryReader

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryReader/readEntries

Found this solution which is a non-standard solution and not recommended to use.

Comment: You won't be able to walk directories on the client for security reasons (at least for the time being).

Comment: Any walkaround using RestFul api?